# Visual Studio 2015 OpenGL freeglut.dll Linker Error

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015, linker-errors, freeglut

So I was playing around with the OpenGL and C++ in Visual Studio 2013 Pro (from dreamspark for students) and everything was fine. Then I decided to try out Visual 2015 Community. After upgrading and rebuilding the project, I'm getting the **LNK1104 error** with **"cannot open freeglut.lib"**.

I've searched through the properties and everything seems fine. I originally installed OpenGL libs with PM by installing **nupengl.core** and adding **#include"GL\glut.h"**. I tried to do some **#defines** as someone pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954344/freeglut-error-lnk1104) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569542/linking-against-nuget-libraries-in-visual-studio-2013) thread, but it's probably outdated by now and I'm not able to follow the instructions at some points. I reinstalled the **nupengl.core** too.

I'm not really fluent with Visual, I've been using it for like a year now and I'm trying my best to understand it more. If anyone has an answer, please make it as clear as possible. Cheers! :D

And of course, sorry for language mistake, as I'm not a native english speaker!

Comment: Just checking, have you add freeglut.lib in the linker's additional dependencies?

Comment: I did, and it didn't solve anything. I believe there is some compatibility problem with the package, since it worked in 2013.

Answer (score 1):

### Resolution

Install the new version 0.1.0.1 of NupenGL and you shouldn't run into any issues. More details: http://mycodelog.com/2015/10/08/opengl-freeglut-in-visual-studio-2015/

---

### Why NupenGL 0.0.0.1 had this issue?

The nupengl.core nuget package installs some files (header and lib) that are necessary to run your OpenGL GLUT application.

In its 0.0.0.1 version, it put out the lib files (including freeglut.lib) under the v120 folder. Visual Studio 2015 looks in the v140 folder.

To resolve the issue in that version, you could create another copy of the folder and name it v140, or change the "**Platform Toolset**" setting in your Visual Studio 2015 project from "Visual Studio 2015 (**v140**)" to "Visual Studio 2013 (**v120**)".

There is no need to do that though since this has been fixed in the 0.1.0.1 version of nupengl.core nuget package.

Github page for project: https://github.com/jcdickinson/NupenGL

Hope that helps.