# Setting linkage type for C++ library installed via Nuget

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30248071/159684) mentions the following method to link to the static version of a C++ library [in this case, "freeglut"] installed via Nuget:

```
Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Referenced Packages->freeglut->Linkage (select static)
```

With Visual Studio 2015 I can't find "Referenced Packages". The only explicit reference to Nuget packages that I have is the packages.config xml file. If I go to the "Manage Nuget packages" section of the project I can install or un-install but I can't find any detail of the package.

I have searched msdn for documentation but all the pages are devoted to the creation of a package, while I need to espress the way to consume such a package. The package in question (Boost Unit Test Framework) can be used header-only, with static or with dynamic linkage and I would like to know where I can decide it.

Maybe I am getting old, but Nuget is a bit too magic for me...

**UPDATE**

This is what I am seeing - you can see that there are Nuget packages installed, in particular boost, but that under the Configuration properties there is no link to "Referenced packages":
[image: screenshot of Nuget installed packages and of the Configuration Properties without a link to "Referenced Packages]

For completeness, the version of VS 2015 Enterprise is:

> 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

and I have checked that when I installed the Boost Test Package I got both the static (.lib) and dynamic (.dll) linkage versions, since the files for my VS version are present in the packages folder.

Comment: _"Maybe I am getting old, but Nuget is a bit too magic for me..."_ +1

Answer (score 2):

> With Visual Studio 2015 I can't find "Referenced Packages".

It depends on **whether you have installed freeglut package into your project**. If you create a C++ project without any NuGet package installed, you could not find the "Referenced Packages":

[image]

**After installed the nuget package** "`freeglut`", the "`Referenced Packages`" and "`Project Master Settings`" would add to the `Configuration Properties`:

[image]

**Update for Boost Package:**
You should install the package `freeglut` to check the "`Referenced Packages`" and "`Project Master Settings`". Since you noticed the different behavior between the package `freeglut`and `Boost`, I would like provide more about [Native NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/native-packages). After installed the `freeglut` and `Boost` in to your project, you can find the `freeglut.targets` and `boost.targets` in the packages folder(..\packages\freeglut.2.8.1.15\build\native & packages\boost.1.64.0.0\build\native), open them with notepad or VS, you will noticed that:

In `freeglut.targets`:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Debug and static and RuntimeLibraryNull" Condition="( $(Configuration.ToLower().IndexOf('debug')) &gt; -1 ) And '$(Linkage-freeglut.ToLower())' == 'static' And ('$(RuntimeLibrary)' == '')">
<RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebug</RuntimeLibrary>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup Label="Release and static and RuntimeLibraryNull" Condition="( $(Configuration.ToLower().IndexOf('debug')) == -1 ) And '$(Linkage-freeglut.ToLower())' == 'static' And ('$(RuntimeLibrary)' == '')">
<RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreaded</RuntimeLibrary>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Label="Debug and ltcg and RuntimeLibraryNull" Condition="( $(Configuration.ToLower().IndexOf('debug')) &gt; -1 ) And '$(Linkage-freeglut.ToLower())' == 'ltcg' And ('$(RuntimeLibrary)' == '')">
<RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreadedDebug</RuntimeLibrary>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Label="Release and ltcg and RuntimeLibraryNull" Condition="( $(Configuration.ToLower().IndexOf('debug')) == -1 ) And '$(Linkage-freeglut.ToLower())' == 'ltcg' And ('$(RuntimeLibrary)' == '')">
<RuntimeLibrary>MultiThreaded</RuntimeLibrary>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will add the options "`Referenced Packages`" and "`Project Master Settings`" via `PropertyGroup` in to the C++ properties.

But in the `boost.targets` file, only:

```
   <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\lib\native\include\;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

So whether the "`Referenced Packages`" and "`Project Master Settings`" will be added is based on the .targets file in the package`s folder.

> If I go to the "Manage Nuget packages" section of the project I can install or un-install but I can't find any detail of the package.

On the right of the "Manage Nuget packages" section of the project, you can notice some more detail Description:

[image]

> I have searched msdn for documentation but all the pages are devoted to the creation of a package, while I need to espress the way to consume such a package.

You can refer to the document [Consume Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/overview-and-workflow) for how to consume a package.

> The package in question (Boost Unit Test Framework) can be used header-only, with static or with dynamic linkage and I would like to know where I can decide it.

You can decide it on the Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Referenced Packages->freeglut:

[image]

Comment: That is missing from my Properties. I have General, Debugging, VC++ Directories. I don't have "Project Master Settings" and "Referenced Packages". If I go to Manage Nuget Packages, it results that Boost is installed (and, in fact, I am using its headers).

Comment: I added a screenshot for better clarity

Comment: @Francesco, I'm sorry not to provide you with a detailed answer, because I afraid too much information will bring you troubled. Since your update question involves more info, I have updated my answer with more detail info, you can check the Update for Boost Package for detail.

Comment: actually the update info is very useful: it appears that the boost package is "different" (in its .targets) from the freeglut example and so I don't find the section. Why do you say "troubles"? more information is welcome! Is there a link on MSDN about this target so that maybe I can modify it myself.

Comment: @Francesco, Sorry, I also don`t know that link on MSDN :( . If possilbe, hope you can get some help from:https://hmemcpy.com/2015/03/adding-a-custom-property-page-to-existing-project-types-in-visual-studio/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx

Comment: Thanks. In the meanwhile I opened an issue on github wrt this topic: https://github.com/sergey-shandar/getboost/issues/34

Answer (score 2):

Boost is using auto-linking. It means, the Boost source code decides which library (file) to use depending on build environment and configuration.

**Update** Here's the process

1. You add [the Boost headers only NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/boost/) to your project.
2. Depending on what are you using and build configuration, Boost may require additional libraries (lib files). In this case, you will receive a compilation/linking error.
3. Depending on the compilation/linking error, you add to your project additional NuGet packages with precompiled Boost libraries from [here](https://github.com/sergey-shandar/getboost/blob/master/releases/1.65.md#precompiled-libraries)

I agree, the process is not obvious. To improve it, Boost should finalize their modularization first. I mean, when Boost libraries (headers and binaries) can be shipped separately.

Comment: Thanks @sergey but I was under the impression that auto linking was avoiding the need to specify things like vc140, mt, d... but I still have to choose if I want to consume the library header only, static or dynamic, no?

Comment: I already did that, in fact as you can see in the screenshot I have both the boost package and the precompiled libraries (in the screenshot you can see e.g. bzip2). Furthermore I have checked that the .lib and .dll files of the Test library are present on my system, for the various setup (debug, release, and so on). But my question is: how can I choose if in my .exe I want to consume a dynamic or a static library? Right now I am manually linking to avoid unneded recompilation but this defeats the purpose of auto-linking...

Comment: Btw thanks for your efforts mantaining the nuget boost packages, they are much appreciated!

Comment: @Francesco I see. The one way is to change how Boost select packages is to change your C++ project configuration. Another way is to add "BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB" and then manually link packages to your code using "#pragma" or build configuration. Currently, Boost NuGet packages only deliver libraries and relay on auto-linking. You may add a feature request to GetBoost but I (or someone else) need to design how this feature will work in all cases.